# How to update JSON file by pure javascript AJAX call through HTTP POST method?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, http, godaddy-api

First Question:
I have been trying to figure out how to update a JSON file through HTTP POST method when both files (HTML and JSON files) are on the same server (ex. Godaddy or AWS). At this point, it is working and sending data to the server as expected, but the JSON file is not updating. I believe I am missing something here. Is it Godaddy API? Check out my codes below:

Second Question:
Is there anyway to add authentication HTTP request? ex. only the user who has access or credential would be able to submit this data change request.

Here is the HTML file

```
<body>
 <button id="my-button">Click Me</button>
 <script>
      document.getElementById('my-button').addEventListener('click', dataRequest);
           function dataRequest (){
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open('POST','my-data.json', true);
                xhttp.send('Name=YOYO&PhoneNumber=777-777-7777');
               }
 </script>
```

Here is my-data.json

> { "Name" : "First Name Last Name",
>        "PhoneNumber" : "888-777-9999" }

Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 0):

POSTing data to a URL handled by a static file won't do anything.

If you want to change the data on the server, you'll need to write some server side code to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you give me some examples of the server side code I will need to write? Is it API? or HTTP service? Thanks

Comment: "Can you give me some examples of the server side code I will need to write?" — Not really. It's pretty basic stuff though. Start by picking a programming language. "Is it API? or HTTP service?" — Yes, both.